# access database with password connection does not work

Tags: c#

When program connect to db without password it connect and its works for read or write data on db. I encrypted the db with password but the connection does not work. make this error  **Cannot open database .  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt**.
I installed the access database engine 2007 and 2010 but its not working.
I have 2013 office and 8.1 OS. I need to connecting with password?
the connection string :

```
<add name="con" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\visitor_db.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=2015;"/>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, There are a few things you should note specifically 1) Titles should give the basic information about your problem - Salutations like "hi" have no place there (or, anywhere in a question for that matter). 2) You should explain your problem fully, including any error mressage you see - "doesn't work" is not a description we can work with. Check out the [help] for more info

Comment: the wrong are ->  Cannot open database ''.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.

Comment: @Jamiec sory my english isnt good

Comment: @elias - That is ok, your English is plenty good enough. Update your question with more information rather than posting here in the comments.

Comment: How did you encrypt it? Did you just put a password on the database? Can you show us your connection string?

Comment: @DougDawson i encrypt it like this steps : open access \ choose database ans open it as exclusive \ then file \ encrypt database

Comment: @DougDawson look to my answer ,its work finally

Comment: @Jamiec look to my answer ,its work finally

Answer (score 0):

i solve it , the problem was the way of encryption , i installed ms access 2007 and create the same db that built by access 2013 and encrypt it , now i can open it with access 2013 with password connection , thanks

Comment: Thanks for coming back and giving an answer!